# Extract link information from wikipedia dump

Tags: java, wikipedia-api

I want to process a wikipedia dump so that for each wikipedia page, I can obtain a list of (hyperlink text,page url), one for each in-link (into wikipedia) in the page. For example, for the [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance_Armstrong),

```
(road racing cyclist,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_bicycle_racing)  
(Tour de France,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_France)  
Union Cycliste Internationale,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Cycliste_Internationale)  
..
```

Is there a library for doing this?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: I belive the hyperlink text isn't stored anywhere, so doing this will require parsing either Wikitext or the rendered HTML of the article.